# Difficulty understanding nodejs documentation

Tags: node.js

I'm really confused about this section

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener

`The requestListener is a function which is automatically added to the 'request' event.`

What does the term "added" specifically mean?

Also for here
http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request

What does the the code directly beneath mean `function (request, response) { }`?  Does it mean that that function gets passed each time there is a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is any help the statement

```
var app = http.createServer( function reqlistener(request, response){...} ).listen(1337);
```

where the function `reqlistener` is the requestListener argument, is equivalent to the following

```
var app = http.createServer().listen(1337);
app.on('request', function reqlistener(request, response){...} );
```

So it is just a shortcut for providing a listener for event `request` during server start itself. The event `request` is emitted for each request once when received by the server.

Answer (score 2):

The requestListener is a lsitener that listens to the 'request' event. Each time a request event is emitted, the requestListener is executed. You pass a function.

That function you pass, should match:

```
function (request, response) { }
```

I believe there is an example at the main page of nodejs.org.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

So each time a request-event is emitted, this function is 'called'.

```
function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      res.end('Hello World\n');
    }
```

With req and res a parameters. (Request and response).

Comment: I'm confused still... _The requestListener is a function which is automatically added to the 'request' event._  So this listener function is added to the request event?  I thought the listener function executes each time there is a request.

Comment: Well, I think they mean with 'added', that is bound to the event, that it executes when the event is emitted.

Comment: Indeed, that would be better suited.
They probs meant added as in: When the event is triggered, the function will be triggered too. So the function is added inside the event.